# javastript get "input number" from class by checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, django, input, checkbox

I have a table with 2 columns: checkbox and quantity.

```
<form action="{% url 'create-order' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-responsive table-borderless">
        <thead>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in items %}
            <tr class="align-middle alert border-bottom">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="item" value="{{ item.id }}" onclick={changeQuantityState(this)}>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input" name="quantity" id="qnt" min="0" value=0 type="number" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="submitButton">
        <button type="submit" class="lgbtn green">Go to order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a handler for the checkbox: if checkbox is checked, then I can select the quantity. Otherwise, the quantity disabled.

```js
function changeQuantityState(checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var quantity = document.getElementById('qnt');
        if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
            quantity.disabled = false;
            quantity.value = 1;
        }
        else {
            quantity.disabled = true;
            quantity.value = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

I need change this line: `var quantity = document.getElementById('qnt');` because I need the quantity for the current row in the table, for the current checkbox, but this code line always return first quantity

Comment: Your `event` parameter has access to the element that was clicked (`event.target`, `event.currentTarget` depending on your needs). You can use it to select the element with ID `qnt` (please make sure IDs are unique, use classes if they are not) and then you can do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `document.getElementById('qnt')` will always return the first element that matches the query. You should always have only **one** element that has a specific ID. If the ID is present multiple times change that to something else, like a class. IDs must be unique.

Here's a quick example on how to use `event.currentTarget` to get the input you need. I've used `parentElement.parentElement` to get the `<tr>` element on which I use `querySelector` to select the input that's next to the checkbox.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

const handleCheckboxChange = (ev) => {
    const quantityInput = ev.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.quantity');
  
  if (ev.target.checked) {
    console.log('Would enable input', quantityInput);
    // enable input
  } else {
    console.log('Would disable input: ', quantityInput);
    // disable input
  }
}

checkboxes.forEach((c) => c.addEventListener('change', handleCheckboxChange));
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input placeholder="Quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input placeholder="Quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input placeholder="Quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!
`const quantity = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.input');` - it's works for me (my input number in class "input")